# sql query with commated separated values

Tags: mysql

Hi my table with values like this

```
post_id  name
 1        a,b 
 2       a,b,d
 3       c,d
```

how to take it to

```
post_id   name
  1         a
  1         b
  2         a
  2         b
  2         d
  3         c
  3         d
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  post_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) name
FROM
  mytable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
ON LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(name)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  post_id,
  n.digit
```

You can take the max number of concatenation on `name` field to use for making `INNER JOIN` clause dynamically by bellow query:

```
select MAX(length(name) - length(replace(name, ',', ''))) as numOfConcate
```